# Trying to find and replace a string from file

Tags: c, file, replace

```
    void replaceString(char* file, char* str, char* replace)
    {
        FILE* fp = fopen(file,"rt");
        char buffer[BUFFER];
        while(fgets(buffer,BUFFER,fp)!=NULL)
        {
            char* s;
            s=strstr(buffer,str);
            if(s!=NULL)
            {
                strcpy(s,replace);
                printf("%s is replaced by %s\n",str,replace);
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        char* file= "text.txt";
        replaceString(file,"is","was");
        printFile(file);
        return 0;
    }
```

Guys I am new to file operations, trying to find and replace a string by another. please help! I am trying to open the file in "rt" mode. Saw this in some example code. Not sure about the mode. I am guessing that I need to use a temp.txt file to do that! Can it be done in a single file without using any other file?

Comment: Only if the replacement is the same length as the string it replaces.  And you'll need to read up on `fseek` and `fwrite`.

Comment: Can somebody provide the source code to do this??

Comment: The principle of SO is that you ask questions that can be given a reasonable answer and that can help others. "Can you provide source code to do this?" is very easy in some sense with "Yes, I can, but I won't!" - but that's not really helpful for anyone else!

Comment: "Can it be done in a single file without using any other file" --> Yes (even if string length differ), but it is more challenging then writing another file.  Usually it is better and more secure to use another file should the operation err partway, need for back-up, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some of the errors in your algorithm.

- You read **and look at** one BUFFER of chars at a time, with no overlap. What if `str` appears between buffers? (i.e. the first part of `str` is at the end of a buffer and the second part is at the start of the next buffer).
- You try to overwrite `str` with `replace` directly in the buffer using `strcpy`. What if both strings are of different length? If `replace` is shorter than `str`, you'd still have the end of `str` there and if `replace` is longer, it will overwrite the text following `str`
- Even if they are the same length, `strcpy` adds the final 0 char at the end of the copy (that's how they tell you where the string ended). you DEFINITIVELY don't want that. Maybe `strncpy` is a better suggestion here, although it will still not work if both strings aren't the same length.
- You replace the strings in the buffer but do nothing with the "corrected" buffer! The buffer is not the file, the content of the file was COPIED into the buffer. So you changed the copy and then nothing. The file will not change. You need to write your changes into a file, preferably a different one.

Writing such a replace isn't as trivial as you might think. I may try and help you, but it might be a bit over your head if you're just trying to learn working with files and are still not fully comfortable with strings.

Doing the replace in a single file is easy if you have enough memory to read the entire file at once (if `BUFFER` is larger than the file size), but very tricky if not especially in your case where `replace` is longer than `str`.

Answer (score 2):

This code replaces all occurences of 'orig' text. You can modify as your needing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void
replaceAllString(char *buf, const char *orig, const char *replace)
{
    int olen, rlen;
    char *s, *d;
    char *tmpbuf;

    if (!buf || !*buf || !orig || !*orig || !replace)
        return;

    tmpbuf = malloc(strlen(buf) + 1);
    if (tmpbuf == NULL)
        return;


    olen = strlen(orig);
    rlen = strlen(replace);

    s = buf;
    d = tmpbuf;

    while (*s) {
        if (strncmp(s, orig, olen) == 0) {
            strcpy(d, replace);
            s += olen;
            d += rlen;
        }
        else
            *d++ = *s++;
    }

    *d = '\0';

    strcpy(buf, tmpbuf);
    free(tmpbuf);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char str[] = "malatya istanbul madrid newyork";

    replaceString(str, "malatya", "ankara");
    printf("%s\n", str);
    replaceString(str, "madrid", "tokyo");
    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`"rt"` mode is for read only. Use `"r+"` mode. That opens the file for both read and write.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at using a buffer and work on this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( ) {
    char buff[BUFSIZ];      // the input line
    char newbuff[BUFSIZ];   // the results of any editing
    char findme[] = "hello";
    char replacewith[] = "world";
    FILE *in, *out;

    in = fopen( "file.txt", "r" );
    out= fopen( "new.txt", "w" );

    while ( fgets( buff, BUFSIZ, in ) != NULL ) {
        if ( strstr( buff, findme ) != NULL ) {
            // do 1 or more replacements
            // the result should be placed in newbuff
            // just watch you dont overflow newbuff...
        } else {
            // nothing to do - the input line is the output line
            strcpy( newbuff, buff );
        }
        fputs( newbuff, out );
    }

    fclose( in );
    fclose( out );
    return 0;
}
```