# Reading specified lines below a found string

Tags: c

I'm going to create a simple database bank account in C-language but I haven't quite figured out how I'm gonna fetch data for a specific account already created and sent to a file. I was thinking of doing a search from the beginning of the file using `fseek` for an account number specified since all account numbers will be unique. Is there a way to read the the amount of lines specified below that account number once it is found? For e.g in my file `accounts.txt` there will be the accounts

```
Account #      : 13398             
First Name     : Eric             
Last Name      : Walters             
Parish         : St.tofu             
Year of Birth  : 1980             
Age            : 34             
Savings Period : 5 year(s)     
Password       : Eric1             
Account #      : 13398             
Account balance: $0.00            
====================================
```

I want to search through the file for the account number and fetch it along with everything else 10 lines below it and display it on the screen if this is possible then say 'aye' and point me to a certain area I should study to achieve this and when I'm successful i'll post my coding here to show what I have done.

Comment: It is easily accessible in case fseek record number of accounts in fixed-length records.

Answer (score 2):

`fseek()` allows you to skip a certain number of bytes in each file. If your lines are not always the same length, you will have to read the entire file, not just to search for the account numbers, but also to find the ten newlines that delimit each account. To do this, you are better off using `fgets()`.

The steps would be something like this

```
foreach line in file
    if line starts with "Account Number"
        if the number is the one you want
            print the next 10 lines
        else
            skip the next 10 lines
    else
        keep looking
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `fseek` is used to move the file pointer not for searching. For search text, i.e. account id in your case, there is some examples [Trying to find and replace a string from file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054077/trying-to-find-and-replace-a-string-from-file-in-c). To write your own code, learning the basic use of [file handling functions](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/07/c-file-handling/) is enough. Furthermore, since your data is structured (every 11 lines represent one account), you code can be accelarated. At last, what you are trying to do is what database software offers and it is hard too implement your own database as fast as commercial software.

Answer (score 0):

You could search in the file, but that would be a bit tedious. Even more tedious if you wanted to modify the account details.

Why don't you use [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html):

> It is designed to replace fopen().

?